# enable hyphenation in a single paragraph

Tags: hyphenation

Many people want to disable hyphenation in a small block of text.  I have the opposite problem: I have disabled hyphenation throughout my document, and I want to enable it for just one paragraph.  Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Specifically, I use

```
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
```

to disable hyphenation throughout the document.  Is there a way to enable it for a single paragraph?

I see, from the `hyphenat` documentation, that the "none" option executes this code:

```
\hyphenpenalty=0
\exhyphenpenalty=0
\relax
```

So I tried to use brackets to create a separate code block in which the penalties were eased, like this:

```
{ 
  \hyphenpenalty=10000
  \exhyphenpenalty=10000
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do....
}
```

But it didn't work. The "Lorem ipsum" passage was still unhyphenated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why anybody would want to disable hyphenation.

However, the settings

```
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\exhyphenpenalty=10000
```

completely inhibit it, which is what the `none` option to `hyphenat` does:

```
\DeclareOption{none}%
    {\hyphenpenalty=10000\exhyphenpenalty=10000\relax}
```

If you want to reenable it for a single paragraph, the simplest way is to say

```
Lorem ipsum ... amet
{\hyphenpenalty=50 \exhyphenpenalty 50\par}

The following paragraph will not be hyphenated
```

Or define a new environment:

```
\newenvironment{hyphenatedparagraph}
 {\par\hyphenpenalty=50 \exhyphenpenalty 50 }
 {\par}
```

and then

```
\begin{hyphenatedparagraph}
Lorem ipsum ... amet
\end{hyphenatedparagraph}
```

will do the same.