# Disable hyphenation for an entire paragraph

Tags: paragraphs, hyphenation

How can I disable hyphenation for an entire paragraph without changing the hyphenation of its words throughout the rest of the text? And of course, maintaining the paragraph alignment!

Thanks, in advice.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/241313/107497 shows how to do the exact opposite, so I think you'd be able to switch the numbers around and get what you want.

Comment: What do you mean by “maintaining the paragraph alignment”?

Comment: Just a right justified paragraph!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set `\hyphenpenalty=10000` and `\exhyphenpenalty=10000`, so TeX sees hyphens as “infinitely bad” and avoids them. Add `\sloppy` if you want to make TeX obey margins at all costs, adding extra inter word spaces to preserve the margins justification.

You can have an environment to do that for you:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{nohyphens}{%
  \par
  \hyphenpenalty=10000
  \exhyphenpenalty=10000
  \sloppy % Makes TeX obey margins by stretching inter word spaces
}{\par}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{nohyphens}
\lipsum[2]
\end{nohyphens}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the nil language from babel:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[nil,ngerman]{babel}

\textwidth=3cm
\begin{document}
deutscher Textabschnitt mit Trennungen

{\selectlanguage{nil}%
deutscher Textabschnitt mit Trennungen\par
}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\begin{hyphenrules}{nohyphenation}...\end{hyphenrules}`.